# Corporate Sales; accessing private static variable with linker error

Tags: c++, static, linker, undefined

***EDIT: This has been solved. Please take a look at my second coding to see what was edited to fix the linker error problem. Please close this thread if it is possible. 
Thanks for your answers/response/feedback <3***

I am trying to access my private static variable to return the total corporate sales (Year_Sales) with function getvalue(). I am trying to trigger the function with

```
cout << DivisionSale[0].getvalue();
```

but I get the following error...

> [linker error] undefined reference; private static variable

**Here is my coding for the project**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// class declaration

class DivSales  // The 6 divisions will use this

{

      private:
              // Holds the total corporate sales for all divisions
              static int Year_Sales;

      public:
              static int Qtrsale[4]; // Elements for sale figures, 4 quarterly sales
              static void AddSales (int,int,int,int); // calculates annual ammount
              int Sales(int); // output
              static int getvalue() { return Year_Sales; } 

};

// This member function takes arguments and is copied into array holding sales data

// Year_Sales contains total of the 4 sales

void DivSales::AddSales(int sale1, int sale2, int sale3, int sale4)

{

      // arrays 0 through 3 store the quarterly sales
      Qtrsale[0] = sale1;
      Qtrsale[1] = sale2;
      Qtrsale[2] = sale3;
      Qtrsale[3] = sale4;

      // private variable access
      // combines the 4 arguments
      Year_Sales = Year_Sales + sale1 + sale2 + sale3 + sale4;

}

// returns values of quarterly sales for each division

// Used for table formatting in main

int DivSales::Sales(int n)

{

    // Qtrsale[n] holds value from input to return for output

    // returns sale(n) 

    int value = Qtrsale[n];
    return value;

}

// this function is triggered if user enters a negative quarterly sale value

void error()

{

     system("cls");
     cout << "You have entered a negative value. Restart program and try again";
     cout << "Press any key to restart program\n";
     system("pause");
     exit(0);

}

// Overload constructer

// Definition of the static member of DivSales class

// for access to the private static variable

int DivSales::Year_Sales = 0;

// Start main function

int main()

{

    // insurance for protecting the array storage(s)
    const int DS = 6;   
    DivSales DivisionSale[DS];  // 6 division with each of their own array
    int quarter, division; // quarter = 4; division = 6

    // This will pass quarter sales to AddSales
    for (division = 0; division < 6; division++)
    {
        // 4 quarters for array storage
        int Qrt1, Qrt2, Qrt3, Qrt4;

        int Q; // used to check for negative input

        // Prompts the user for quarter sales of each division
        // divisions 1 - 6
        cout << "Enter Sales of Division: " << division + 1 << endl;

        // Each quarter is assigned to Q which is used for error checking.
        // Error checking occurs when negative value is detected
        cout << "Enter Q1 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt1;
        Q = Qrt1;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        cout << "Enter Q2 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt2;
        Q = Qrt2;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        cout << "Enter Q3 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt3;
        Q = Qrt3;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        cout << "Enter Q4 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt4;
        Q = Qrt4;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        // passes Qrt1 through Qrt4 to AddSales
        DivisionSale[division].AddSales(Qrt1,Qrt2,Qrt3,Qrt4);
    }

    cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\t" << "Q1" << "\t" << "Q2" << "\t" << "Q3" << "\t" << "Q4" << endl;

    // table for quarterly sales of each division
    for (division = 0; division < 6; division++)
    {
        cout << "Div " << division + 1;
        for (quarter = 0; quarter < 4; quarter++)
        {
            // calling function Sales 6 times
            cout << "\t" << DivisionSale[division].Sales(quarter);
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\n Total All Division Sales for the Year: ";
    cout << DivisionSale[0].getvalue();       

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

**And here is what I need to do:**

A corporation has six divisions, each responsible for sales to different geographic locations. Design a DivSales class that keeps sales data for a division, with the following members:

• An array with four elements for holding four quarters of sales figures for the division

• A private static variable for holding the total corporate sales for all divisions for the entire year.

• A member function that takes four arguments, each assumed to be the sales for a quarter. The value of the arguments should be copied into the array that holds the sales data. The total of the four arguments should be added to the static variable that holds the total yearly corporate sales.

• A function that takes an integer argument within the range of 0 to 3. The argument is to be used as a subscript into the division quarterly sales array. The function should return the value of the array element with that subscript.

Write a program that creates an array of six DivSales objects. The program should ask the user to enter the sales for four quarters for each division. After the data is entered, the program should display a table showing the division sales for each quarter. The program should then display the total corporate sales for the year.

*Input Validation: Only accept positive values for quarterly sales figures.*

The Linker error is the only error that is standing in my way. I am well aware that there could be some code optimization, but I really need to fix the linker error.

**EDIT: Revised what's static and not static and used int DivSales::Year_Sales**

New coding:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// class declartion

class DivSales  // The 6 divisions will use this

{

      private:
              // Holds the total corporate sales for all divisions
              static int Year_Sales;
              int Qtrsale[4]; // Elements for sale figures, 4 quarterly sales

      public:
              void AddSales (int,int,int,int); // calculates annual ammount
              int Sales(int); // output
              int getvalue() { return Year_Sales; }

};

// This member function takes arguments and is copied into array holding sales data

// Year_Sales contains total of the 4 sales

void DivSales::AddSales(int sale1, int sale2, int sale3, int sale4)

{

      // arrays 0 through 3 store the quarterly sales
      Qtrsale[0] = sale1;
      Qtrsale[1] = sale2;
      Qtrsale[2] = sale3;
      Qtrsale[3] = sale4;

      // private variable access
      // combines the 4 arguments
      Year_Sales = Year_Sales + sale1 + sale2 + sale3 + sale4;

}

// returns values of quarterly sales for each division

// Used for table formatting in main

int DivSales::Sales(int n)

{

    // Qtrsale[n] holds value from input to return for output
    // returns sale(n) 
    int value = Qtrsale[n];
    return value;

}

// this function is triggered if user enters a negative quarterly sale value

void error()

{

     system("cls");
     cout << "You have entered a negative value. Restart program and try again";
     cout << "Press any key to restart program\n";
     system("pause");
     exit(0);

}

// Overload constructer

// Definition of the static member of DivSales class

// for access to the private static variable

int DivSales::Year_Sales;


// Start main function

int main()

{

    // insurance for protecting the array storage(s)
    const int DS = 6;   
    DivSales DivisionSale[DS];  // 6 division with each of their own array
    int quarter, division; // quarter = 4; division = 6

    // This will pass quarter sales to AddSales
    for (division = 0; division < 6; division++)

    {

        // 4 quarters for array storage
        int Qrt1, Qrt2, Qrt3, Qrt4;

        int Q; // used to check for negative input

        // Prompts the user for quarter sales of each division
        // divisions 1 - 6
        cout << "Enter Sales of Division: " << division + 1 << endl;

        // Each quarter is assigned to Q which is used for error checking.
        // Error checking occurs when negative value is detected
        cout << "Enter Q1 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt1;
        Q = Qrt1;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        cout << "Enter Q2 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt2;
        Q = Qrt2;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        cout << "Enter Q3 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt3;
        Q = Qrt3;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        cout << "Enter Q4 Sales: ";
        cin >> Qrt4;
        Q = Qrt4;
        if (Q < 0)
           error();

        // passes Qrt1 through Qrt4 to AddSales
        DivisionSale[division].AddSales(Qrt1,Qrt2,Qrt3,Qrt4);

    }

    cout << "\n----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\t" << "Q1" << "\t" << "Q2" << "\t" << "Q3" << "\t" << "Q4" << endl;

    // table for quarterly sales of each division
    for (division = 0; division < 6; division++)

    {

        cout << "Div " << division + 1;
        for (quarter = 0; quarter < 4; quarter++)

        {

            // calling function Sales 6 times
            cout << "\t$" << DivisionSale[division].Sales(quarter);

        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    cout << "----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\nTotal corporate sales for the year: ";
    cout << "$" << DivisionSale[0].getvalue() << endl;      

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to have a definition for the variable somewhere:

```
int DivSales::Qtrsale[4];
```

You have a declaration in the class, but there also needs to be a definition (in a single place) somewhere in the project.

This has to be a C++ FAQ, but I'm too lazy to look it up right now.

Comment: I have something like int DivSales::Year_Sales = 0; outside the class already.

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem variable was the Qtrsale[4] array.

Comment: Under recommendation I changed static int Qtrsale[4] to private but alas that did nothing.                                                       What is wrong with the Qtrsale[4] array?

Comment: I cannot upvote your answer because you have solved this problem with your suggestion. Thank you very much <3

Comment: On looking a little bit more at the code, it looks to me that `Qtrsale` has no business being `static`.  I think if you make it `private` and get rid of the static (as well as the definition I mention in the answer).  You'll also need to make `AddSales()` a non-static function.  It seems to me that you may need to think about exactly what data and behaviors are tied to an instance of the object (and therefor should not be static) and which are 'outside' of a class instance (and therefore maybe should be static).